# Running a separate executable from a windows service in Golang

Tags: windows, go, windows-services

I have an application written in Go which is designed to be deployed to a Windows server and communicates with other applications via Google Pub/Sub.

On some of the messages, we need to run an external 3rd party developed application to return some data from the database which has to be parsed using some proprietary rules.  We then capture the output of this (stdout), perform some more parsing then marshal the structs and put them on Pub/Sub for consumers to handle.

When running the application interactively, this works absolutely fine.  When running it as a Windows service as a local administrator of the server, it also works fine.

However, when running as a local user or local system account (either with or without desktop interaction), the output from the command I execute while running:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(pathToExecutable, resourceId)
out, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
  return result, fmt.Errorf("got error from command - %v", err)
}
exportData := ExportData{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(out, &exportData); err != nil {
    return result, fmt.Errorf("got error - %v", err)
```

is always empty.  I've tried initialising buffers and passing these to the command, and nothing seems to work, I always receive a `[]bytes` of len 0.

Is there any obvious debugging approaches I can take, or is there some rules around stdout/stderr with Windows services that means this will never work?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Does error from `Output()` say something. It looks you ignore it.

Comment: The output of the command is unmarshalled into the `exportData` struct - this fails as the `out` is a `[]bytes` with length 0.

Comment: To clarify, the error I get the when running the executable occurs at the json Unmarshal method with this error - `unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: I've just tested again, and `out` is an empty slice of bytes and `err` is nil

Comment: Try to provide minimal reproducible example and exact command you tried. Code looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt - I have written a minimal example using a HTTP server that calls another executable in the same directory and it seems to work fine! That leads me to the idea that there is something happening with the external executable when run in the background.  I will have to do some more digging sadly.